# C# Return string value from another class to null value

Tags: c#, string, null, return

Example:

```
public partial class abc1 : Form
{
       public string str__subgrp { get; set; }
       public string str__type { get; set; }
       public string return_str__type { get; set; 

       public abc1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }
       private void savebtn_click(object sender, EventArge e )
       {
            this.str__subgrp = "ABC";
            this.str__type = "123";
            this.return_str__type = "This word is unicode";
       }
}
```

```
public partial class worknow : Form
{
       // ... declare variable in class ....

       public worknow()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void showformbtn_click(object sender, EventArge e )
       {
            string a,b,c;
            using ( var abc1_frm = new abc1())
            {
                 abc1_frm.ShowDialog();
                 a = abc1_frm.str__subgrp;
                 b = abc1_frm.str__type;
                 c = abc1_frm.return_str__type;  // This variable = null

            }
       }
}
```

In the comment line (this variable = null)

Why does the variable `return_str__type` return `null` value?

Comment: You miss the `}` ?? `public string return_str__type { get; set; `

Comment: This does not compile, because you are missing a `}` on the fifth line.

Comment: I sorry about miss } return_str__type = "ภาษาไทย" // <-- Thai Lang.

Answer (score 1):

You can only expect `abc1_frm.return_str__type` to have a value different from null if you make sure that `savebtn_click` is executed before your dialog gets closed. Since you did not tell us exactly how the user (or you as a tester) closes the dialog, and if you disabled the closing button [X], the only advice I can give you is to set a breakpoint in the debugger within that method and check if the code is executed.

Comment: Yes I very sure. And debug my program before close form. And other variable can return value.

Comment: Then check again - more thorougly. Or edit your question and give a more detailed problem description.

Comment: My full variable name : return_plantbl_beneftextforuser // It Return Null Value. And I test change variable name to other : return_plantbl_beneftextforuser_eng  // C# can return value

Comment: I use 2 variable to keep value : return_plantbl_beneftextforuser kepp my default lang. return_plantbl_beneftextforuser_eng keep english value. Why return_plantbl_beneftextforuser return null value ?

Comment: Variable name in 2 class not same string.I don't know about this error.And C# compiler has not error show.

Comment: @Siwakorn.ap: next time you ask a question like this, you *please* copy/paste the original code directly from Visual Studio here to SO (you obviously did not).

Answer (score 1):

Assignment of `return_str__type` property happens in `savebtn_click` function.
Why do you expect that this function invokes?
Try to set up `savebtn` button as `AcceptButton` of `abc1` from, or find a way how to define `savebtn_click` as default event of the form.
And please make something with your style code, my eyes are bleeding :)

Comment: Variable name in 2 class not same string.I don't know about this error.And C# compiler has not error show me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. It has to do with scope.  Try declaring **return_str__type** as a **public static** type and see if it works.  Not always the best practice, but may just work.